# Javascript Async with map

Tags: javascript

This is a silly example, I'm not good at syntax I try to understand how to make it work with async as it doesn't (beware I need the map):

```
  const list = ["hello", "world"]
    

  async function test() {

    let allTexts = Promise.all(list.map(async word => word.upperCase()));
    return allTexts;
  }

  test().then(result => alert(result.join('')))
```

Solved through comments below : use then + Use toUpperCase instead. – evolutionxbox

Comment: `test` will only return a promise, so that's what you call `toString()` on. You need to `await test()` or `test.then(result => alert(result))`

Comment: The inner function call doesn't need to be flagged `async` unless it needs to `await`, which apparently it doesn't. Is `upperCase()` an async function? That would be strange.

Comment: Is the `alert()` call within an `async` function? If not, you need the `.then()` chaining.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: use `alert` inside the `then`.

Comment: @VLAZ I tried alert(test().then(result => result.join(''))) but doesn't work ? still a promise object...

Comment: @tadman you're right it doesn't but in real I may need.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I just tried see update but still doesn't work

Comment: `word.upperCase` is incorrect and will throw an error. Use `toUpperCase` instead.

Comment: @evolutionxbox oh sh... that's what that stupid ! thanks :)

Comment: The original async issue is solved by the link I gave.

Comment: @evolutionxbox ah sorry I looked at it but was so lengthy I couldn't see ;)

Comment: It's good to read it. Even if it is quite lengthy